# How can I make two parameters in a stored procedure follow the results of parameter 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two Parameters, Parameter 1 is `@ResourceID` and Parameter 2 is `@OrgUnit`
If I run the first execute

`dm2699` is an example of a `resourceID` whilst `CORCO1CFOVEITC` is an example of `OrganizationUnit`.

If I run the first execute for ResourceID, I get the results that I want.
If I also run the second execute for OrgUnit or OrganizationID, I get the results that I want. It should always be one entry at a time. But my problem lies on the third execute, when the user puts two values on both parameters. What I want to happen is that if when a user puts value on both parameters then I want the results to be exactly the same as the results of Parameter 1.

On my script below, the last condition,  if @ResourceID <> '' and @OrgUnit <> ''..... gives the results of execute procedure 2, which is the results of Parameter 2 and not Parameter 1.

1. `exec [dbo].ExportResourceTime 'dm2699',''`
2. `exec [dbo].ExportResourceTime '','CORCO1CFOVEITC'`
3. `exec [dbo].ExportResourceTime 'dm2699','CORCO1CFOVEITC'`

   ```
   create table #Resources(
       ResourceID nvarchar(30),
       OrganizationID nvarchar(15),
       EffectiveDate datetime
   )

   if @ResourceID <> ''
    begin
    insert into #Resources (ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate)

       select ro.ResourceID, ro.OrganizationID, ro.EffectiveDate from ResourceOrganization ro,
       (select ResourceID, MAX(EffectiveDate) as maxEffectivedate from dbo.ResourceOrganization
       where ResourceID = @ResourceID
       group by ResourceID) as maxresults
       where ro.ResourceID = maxresults.ResourceID
       and ro.EffectiveDate = maxresults.maxEffectivedate
       end



   if @OrgUnit <> ''
   begin
      insert into #Resources (ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate)
      Select  ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate from ResourceOrganization
      where OrganizationID like '' + @OrgUnit + '%'
   end



   if @ResourceID <> '' and @OrgUnit <> ''
   begin
    insert into #Resources (ResourceID,OrganizationID,EffectiveDate)
       select ro.ResourceID, ro.OrganizationID, ro.EffectiveDate from ResourceOrganization ro,
       (select ResourceID, MAX(EffectiveDate) as maxEffectivedate from dbo.ResourceOrganization
       where ResourceID = @ResourceID
       group by ResourceID) as maxresults
       where ro.ResourceID = maxresults.ResourceID
       and ro.EffectiveDate = maxresults.maxEffectivedate
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @ResourceID <> '' and @OrgUnit <> '', all three statements are executed.

**Is that what you want?**

If not, change the single IF statements to nested IF ELSE statements so that only one section is executed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587(v=sql.120).aspx

```
if @ResourceID <> ''

else if @OrgUnit <> ''

else if @ResourceID <> '' and @OrgUnit <> ''
```

Another was to do this is to use the RETURN statement in the stored procedure.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

This will return control back the the calling TSQL.